# Compilation issue while upgrading a website from Visual Studio 2005 to Visual Studio 2008 with framework 2.0 in Windows XP

Tags: .net, licenses.licx, emptylicenseslicx, licenseslicx

upgraded some visualstudio 2005 websites to visualstudio 2008. now it is working fine while debugging.  There is an error while compiling the website. the following is the error.

Error 1 C:\Program Files.............\DirectScanToServer\licenses.licx: Could not transform licenses file into a binary resource.  (1) : error LC0004 : Exception occurred creating type 'OSADirectLicensing.OSADirectLicensedClass, OSADirectLicensing, Version=1.0.3637.23829, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null System.ComponentModel.LicenseException: Invalid License
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.CreateWithContext(Type type, LicenseContext creationContext, Object[] args)
   at System.ComponentModel.LicenseManager.CreateWithContext(Type type, LicenseContext creationContext)
   at System.Tools.LicenseCompiler.GenerateLicenses(String fileContents, String targetPE, ITypeResolutionService resolver, DesigntimeLicenseContext ctx)' C:\Program Files.........\DirectScanToServer\licenses.licx http://localhost/DirectScanToServer/

Comment: That's a licensing issue with a 3rd party component. Your best bet is to find out where the DirectScanToServer component comes from and contact them regarding the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would talk directly to the producer of the Direct To Scan license and see if you need a different one after upgrading to 2008. What version of .Net was your application targeting before the upgrade and now?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chris' on this one. Alternatively, you can install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) nuget package, and it will make sure there's an empty `Licenses.licx` in your project, before it gets compiled (which is all you need).